# Click counter in PHP (without form)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, counter

I did once counter based on the form. Everything was fine until I have to make changes on the site.

Old code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['b1']) ) {
    $count += 1;
    $_SESSION['count'] = $count;
}

(...)

?>

<form action="start.php" method="post">
    <button id="b1" class="btn" name="b1"> B1 </button>
    <button id="b2" class="btn" name="b2"> B2 </button>
</form>
```

The form makes problems, so I'm looking for another solution. I was told that I tried Ajax , but it works only $_GET for me (I need post)

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
      $.post("start.php", { name: "b1" });
      location.reload();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: check for errors and your developer's console.

Comment: change `{ name: "b1" }` -> `{ b1: 1 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you check for is **b1** but actually you pass **name** with b1 as value

then you need to change your php code to this

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == 'b1' ) {
    $count += 1;
    $_SESSION['count'] = $count;
}

(...)

?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
if( isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == 'b1' ) {
    $_SESSION['count'] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thaks. I've done your way, but the counter shows 1 all the time. Where could be the problem?

Comment: @PjRain i think the problem then in $count it's not declared so it take it as 0 so just see **update** of my answer

Comment: For me it's middle of the night and did not think about it... Of course it helped, thanks :)